# Ignite db timestamp column default to current timestamp fails

Tags: sql, default, ignite, sql-timestamp, current-time

I have just started to used GridGrain Ignite DB community edition version 8.7.5. I am trying to create a simple address table.

```
CREATE TABLE address(id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
line1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
line2 VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
postal_code VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
country_code VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
coordinates GEOMETRY,
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

It gives me following error -

> [IgniteSQLException] Non-constant DEFAULT expressions are not
>   supported [colName=CREATED_AT]

I want default value of `created_at` column to be `current_timestamp`, that's where it gives me the error. What is the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is currently not supported. Feel free to create a ticket against IGNIITE JIRA.